# Boost:Python is not finding class that is defined in the same directory

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am trying to use Boost to make a C++ class accessible to a Python program. I have defined the files as such (names changed):

```
my-project/
├── source/
│   ├── boostFile.cpp
│   ├── cppClass.cpp
│   └── cppClass.hpp
```

And then have the boostFile.cpp below (again, names changed), where 'example' is defined as a class in the .hpp file and exampleFunc1 and exampleFunc2 are defined in the .hpp and implemented in the .cpp file.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    class_<example>("example")
        .def("example_func1", &boost::exampleFunc1)
        .def("example_func2", &boost::exampleFunc2)
    ;
}
```

I get this error from VS Code and when I try to build the boost file:

```
identifier "example" is undefined
```

I have updated the includePath in VSCode to include the current directory.

Comment: You need to include `cppClass.hpp` in the file where you define the module but you should first use a different name (fort he module, the class, etc.), using `boost` is just asking for troubles everywhere.

Comment: The symbol `boost` is already a namespace, you can't use it for other types in the same scope.

Comment: @Holt I am not using 'boost' as the class name, I was just using that as an example. I will try included the hpp file